# How to get char type in 2D list input?

Tags: python, list, char, user-input

How to get char type input in 2D list in python?
I am running below code...but it is giving `EOFerror`.

```
r,c = list(map(int,input().split()))
matrix = [[input() for x in range (c)] for y in range(r)]
```

Required O/P--->

```
matrix = [['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'G'],
          ['O', 'W', 'W', 'O', 'O'],
          ['O', 'O', 'O', 'W', 'O'],
          ['G', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'O'],
          ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'G']]
```

Error coming-->

```
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my query using below code

```
matrix=[]
    for i in range(r):

        a=list(map(str,input().split()))
        matrix.append(a)
```

But still if anyone know why the error has come earlier then please respond..

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the code in terminal or in an IDE? I guess it's a problem of Sublime Text. Install SumlimeREPL or `CTRL+D` might help you.